# how to exclude mongodb _id field in php result

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to exclude the _id field from PHP-MongoDB result.below is my PHP script.What I can add to the script to exclude _id from the output.

```
<?php
try
{
    $connection = new Mongo('mongodb://user:pass@xxxx.mlab.com:xxxxx/stats');
    $database   = $connection->selectDB('stats');
    $collection = $database->selectCollection('stat');
}
catch(MongoConnectionException $e)
{
    die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());
}

$cursor = $collection->find();

echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($cursor));



?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:-

```
$cursor->fields(array('_id'=>false));
```

After the find...

Comment: it's Worked.Thank you so much.